Scaling On-Chain Operations with ERC1155 on Polygon Blockchain
I’m currently building a platform that bridges a centralized backend with a Smart Contract on Polygon. The Smart Contract follows the ERC1155 standard, which enables batch token minting. The core idea of the application is to perform minting and other on-chain operations on behalf of customers who may not be familiar with Web3 technology.
At present, I’m designing and coding the system architecture to handle operations at scale, aiming to support hundreds of concurrent operations. For example, consider 10-20 customers simultaneously minting 100 tokens each — this would create a substantial payload for the blockchain.
Currently, my backend utilizes a single blockchain wallet account to pack requests into batches, process operations, await confirmation, and then repeat the cycle. However, a significant limitation of this approach is that a single account can only process one operation at a time, which bottlenecks the system.
I’m exploring the idea of using multiple blockchain wallet accounts to simultaneously process operations, thereby increasing system capacity and throughput.
Do you have any recommendations or best practices for scaling such a system? Are there alternative approaches, frameworks, or architectural patterns you would suggest to efficiently manage high on-chain transaction volumes?
